# how to sign in to two Azure Active Directories

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a web application where users have to authenticate against our active directory. This works fine. But when a user already has session with another Azure Active Directory say a corporate office 365 or something, the user gets an error trying to authenticate to us. 
Is there some sort of setting (a domain ID, or some sort of token ID which makes it possible to differentiate these two sessions and make it possible to use our waad as a stand alone authentication service?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the actual error and the services you are authenticating against?

In general you can easily differentiate between different logged in users by using the login_hint in ADAL and passing the UPN of the user who you wish to access from the cache. ADAL will do the heavily lifting of looking in to the cache and prompting the user for credentials if the tokens for that user has expired.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but the problem is that when I am connected to say the azure management portal with my corporate account and I start a new browser tab and go to my web application, I get redirected to waad but it will immediately connect me with the credentials of my Corporate Account.

Comment: I have the following error: AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx@xxx.nl' from external identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/abcdefg-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdefg/' is not supported for application 'https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/abcdefghijklm'. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant. Please sign out and sign in again with an Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: You need to use "In Private" or equivalent. The session cookies will cause you to always log in with the most recent logged in user when accessing a URL that can serve either user such as the Azure portal.

Comment: But that is exactly what I can't explain to my customers. Is there a way to tag those session cookies so they will not interfere with each other.